# Install windows service with cc.net and MS Build

Tags: .net, msbuild, windows-services, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using cc.net and MS build to to build my client and Win service project.
This is how the Services is being built, with this:
**Is it possibloe to automatically install this as windows services?**

```
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>C:\CCBuild\Git\Dev\Services\ServiceSetup</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>ServiceSetup.wixproj</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /v:diag</buildArgs>
        <targets>Clean;Build</targets>
        <timeout>480</timeout>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
      </msbuild>
```

and the client:
**Is it possible to run integration test only if the above service was installed and started successfully?**

```
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>C:\CCBuild\Git\Dev\LocalClient\ClientSetup</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>ClientSetup.wixproj</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /v:diag</buildArgs>
        <targets>Clean;Build</targets>
        <timeout>480</timeout>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
      </msbuild>
      <exec>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>/rnf:report2\test-report /rt:Xml-Inline /v:Quiet C:\CCBuild\Git\Dev\LocalClient\Client.IntegrationTests\bin\x86\Debug\Client.IntegrationTests.dll</buildArgs>
        <description>Client Tests</description>
      </exec>
```

Please explain with sample code since cc.net and MsBuild are new to me.
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

1:
I would suggest installing the service manually.
Then get cruise control to stop then start the service.
Otherwise you would need to determine if the service is already installed before trying to.

You can add an exec task you can call `net stop servicename` to stop the service. And then another task after msbuild to start it again (with `net start servicename`).

`net.exe` is a stock windows console app, so it sits in `c:\windows\system32`

2:
If the task above failed (i.e. the stop/build/start failed) then the following tests task would not be executed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But you would only ever want to install the service once per cruise control server.

Answer (score 1):

For installation of a windows service you could either use the command line and [Installutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or - if you like it a bit more convenient - you write an MSBuild script and use [WindowsService tasks from the MSBuild.ExtensionPack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/258a18b7-2cf7-330b-e6fe-8bc45db381b9.htm).

If you configure your CCNET server to execute the tasks in a sequence, the Gallio task will only be executed if preceding tasks succeeded.

```
<tasks>
  <!-- 1st... -->
  <msbuild>
    <!-- build server -->
  </msbuild>
  <!-- either... -->
  <exec>
    <!-- execute Installutil -->
    <executable>cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/C C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe YourAssembly</buildArgs>
  </exec>
  <!-- or... -->
  <msbuild>
    <!-- execute WindowsService MSBuild script -->
  </msbuild>
  <!-- then... -->
  <msbuild>
    <!-- build client -->
  </msbuild>
  <!-- finally... -->
  <exec>
    <!-- execute Gallio -->
  </exec>
</tasks>
```

This is how it should work with a simple windows service. I'm a little uncertain regarding the output of your service setup WiX project. If it produces some fancy ServiceSetup.msi including a [ServiceInstall](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_serviceinstall.htm) then you should know best yourself which parameters are to be passed.